# Unwanted li tags created by shiny nabvarPage

Tags: html, css, shiny

Im developing an app with shiny using navbarPage, but looking at the html there're unwanted li tags that are not defined in my code. Is this a known bug? What can I do to fix it?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <span class="navbar-brand">app with shiny</span>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav shiny-tab-input" id="top-bar-nav-panel" data-tabsetid="2774">
        <li>
          <a href="#tab-2774-1" data-toggle="tab"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#tab-2774-2" data-toggle="tab"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#tab-2774-3" data-toggle="tab"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#tab-2774-4" data-toggle="tab" data-value="App">
            <i class=" fa fa-rocket fa-fw" role="presentation" aria-label=" icon"></i>
            App
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#tab-2774-5" data-toggle="tab" data-value="Guide">
            <i class=" fa fa-book fa-fw" role="presentation" aria-label=" icon"></i>
            Guide
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#tab-2774-6" data-toggle="tab" data-value="Team">
            <i class=" fa fa-users fa-fw" role="presentation" aria-label=" icon"></i>
            Team
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Here is the code that I use in the shiny app

```
ui <- navbarPage(title = "app with shiny",
  windowTitle = "app with shiny",
  id = "top-bar-nav-panel",  
  theme = shinytheme("lumen"),

  # Head tags
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "css/general.css"),
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "css/space.css"),
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "css/button.css"),
    tags$script(src = "js/console.js"),
  ),

  # Set up shinyalert
  useShinyalert(), 
  # Set up shinyjs 
  useShinyjs(),
  # Set as default panel the one with the id "App"
  selected = "App",
  tabPanel("App", icon = icon("rocket"), #code here),
  tabPanel("Guide", icon = icon("book"), #code here),
  tabPanel("Team", icon = icon("users"), #code here)
)
```

Im also using shinyjs and other R packages, but it's for some stuff that I'll code later .

Answer (score 0):

This CSS seems to "fix" some of that unwated whitespace created by those blank li tags, but they're still there.

```
.navbar-header > * {
    margin-right: -4em;
    margin-bottom: -4em;
}
```